# Increase minimum reputation required for posting an answer on SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, spam

It happens quite often that low-quality questions receive spam answers. Just a few hours ago, I came across [one such question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269521/removing-timeline-view-theme-on-facebook) (now 10k+ only).

The above post received a spam answer from a user with just one reputation point. Why isn't there any mechanism to stop such users from posting answers on SO?

I know we can flag specific individual answers, but why should those answers be shown in the first place? Can't we do something similar to what we do with suggested edits? Answers from users with minimal reputation could be placed in a queue for moderation before being displayed.

Would there be any consequences to this approach? What do you think?

Comment: This mechanism already exists.  High-rep users can place a protection flag on questions.  This protection prevents low-rep users from creating answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course there are consequences. I would say the biggest strength of SO is that you can get an answer to your question *quickly*. If we delay posts, even only the ones of 1 rep users, we somewhat lose that.

You have to weight the spam against the speed that answers can be given. IMO, it's no match -- spam is dealt with very easily, and getting an answer quickly is almost priceless.

And, especially, managing the queue of not-yet-approved posts takes considerably more work than just flagging the spam.

Comment: (+1)I think you are right. Spam answers are so frustrating sometimes.

Comment: +1. Also, everyone on SO, even the top users, started out as a 1 reputation user, and if each new user were discouraged from posting their first answer because it took a while to show up (and therefore might have prevented them from gaining upvotes), the site might lose so many productive members.